# What is the max size of a string in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm importing csv files from Gmail attachments into an existing Google Spreadsheet.

I use the getDataAsString() to hold the entire csv contents.  I've tried it varying sizes up to ~6000 characters.  Is there a maximum number of characters this string can take?

Comment: The limit will probably be the Gmail attachment size rather than the string length.... easy to test though, see the answers in the post linked in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The limit for strings in Google Apps Script is **67,108,864 (67 million) characters**. You can try it yourself with this function:

```
function strtest() {
  var str = "a";
  while (1) {
    str = str + str;
  }
}
```

Outputs:

[image]

I am not sure if there is a way to increase this through other means (for example, [there is a fix for this in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818080/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-67108864-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate)).

Answer (score 0):

GAS is based on Javascript, and apparently there is no JS string variable limit:

[javascript object max size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926263/javascript-object-max-size-limit)