# What are the technical limitations of Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have experienced errors in Google Apps Script where errors are thrown as strings and arrays become too large.

I'm looking to see if anyone has anymore information on what the exact limitations of GAS are, with regard to things like size of arrays. If there are other similar limitations I would also like to know about them.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071831/what-is-the-max-size-of-a-string-in-google-apps-script) but that only helps with the string size case, and I'm pretty sure the answer is inaccurate.

There is also [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) but it doesn't include things like string maximum size.

I posted on the GSuite support forums, but was told to try stackoverflow instead.

I can run some experiments to find the limits of strings and arrays, but I'd prefer a more complete answer if possible.

Comment: Even if you document everything here, whatever is not officially documented is subject to change at Google's whim

Comment: To add, the linked question's  answers says string limit as 68M. It is also not valid now. It's currently at 268 million. I don't think it's just a arbitrary limit though. It may also be subject to memory limitations.

Comment: @TheMaster I agree it's not ideal to list here, but given Google has not produced any documentation on this perhaps it is better to have potentially out-dated information available rather than none at all.

Comment: Meh. The reason none of this is documented is probably because for normal/ ordinary users, they'll never hit  the limit. If you're hitting it, you're doing something wrong.